# Architecture. WCF+SHAREPOINT services

Tags: wcf, sharepoint, authentication, architecture

I have separate layer with WCF services. 
And I have sharepoint website.

The aim to allow login for mobile devices to WCF layer and in the same time to sharepoint web site.
Sharepoint will be used like secured database.
I need somehow to check user when he will login to WCF layer and the hard part to authenticate him in SharePoint website.
I need any help because I really don’t know a lot about this topic. Will appreciate any answers

Comment: Are your systems and users all on the domain?

Comment: in sharepoint we have users from AD.

Comment: For now choise is basic authentification+SSL. Then i can call sharepoint methods with username and password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your WCF service will not connect to the web pages of the SharePoint site, it will connect SharePoint's web services.

Mobile devices are limited in the authentication they support. Windows authentication may not be supported. So basichttpbinding using basic authentication over SSL is probably the best option. Send the username and password as part of the call, then you can use this username and password in the web service call to the SharePoint web services.